# Can I run NM wire through this type of flex legally

Tags: wiring, code-compliance

This flex is sold along other types of NM wire molding, but I can't find anywhere where this [product](http://www.legrand.us/wiremold/at-home/cord-wraps-and-accessories/cm62-cordmate-ii-flex.aspx#Overview) explicitly allows NM or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the 2015-16 UL White Book, this product is only allowed to contain the following:

- Optical fiber cables (Types: OFNP,OFNR,OFN,OFNG,OFCP,OFCR,OFCR,OFC,OFCG).
- Communications cable (Types: CMP,CMR,CM,CMG,Cross-connect wire).
- Power-limited fire-alarm cable (Types: FPLP,FPLR,FPL).
- Community antenna television cable (Types: CATVP, CATVR,CATV).
- Low-power network-powered broadband communications cable (Types: BLP,BLR,BL).

Which means no NM cable, no lamp cords, no extension cords, nothing but the types of cable listed in the table above.

> ## 2013 UL White Book
>
> ### Cable Routing Assemblies (QBAA)
>
> #### Use and Installation
>
> This category covers routing assemblies for installation of conductive
>   and nonconductive optical fiber cable, communications cable/wire, powerlimited
>   fire-alarm cable, community antenna television cable and lowpower
>   network-powered broadband communications cable. Cable-routing
>   assemblies are intended to be installed in accordance with ANSI/NFPA 70,
>   "National Electrical Code" (NEC). Cable-routing assemblies are only suitable
>   for the installation of cable/wire noted in the following information.
>   Individual routing assembly systems differ in their construction and,
>   therefore, their components are not interchangeable with other routing
>   assemblies or fittings of other systems. This category includes pliable
>   lengths, rigid straight sections, elbows, bends, and fittings such as expansion
>   joints, female and male adapters, and couplings.
>   These products may or may not incorporate end fixtures or covers.
>
> [image]

***NOTES:***
- *I had trouble finding UL marking on this product, so this information could be inaccurate. Check the product/packaging for an official UL mark and listing. Specifically look for the wording "General-use Cable Routing Assembly" and/or "ANSI/UL 2024"*

Answer (score 3):

No, if you're meaning to use it for electrical circuits or hardwiring appliances. It's one of their "Cord Management" solutions & is peel & stick installation. It's for plugged wires, lamp cords or their extension cords, coaxial cables, HDMI's, speaker wires & such.

You'd have to go for their Raceway Products for electrical circuits. These are the typical legal options that are mechanically fastened with screws & there is no & can't be a detached flexible tail sleeve to replace securely anchored armored cable.