# Is it safe to mount a surge protector strip behind a wall-mounted television?

Tags: extension-cord, television, extension

To make my television mount look clean I ran a new extension cord, the tv plug and the cable wire through a wire management system that sticks on the wall. The extension cord is plugged into a 2 foot surge protector which is taped to the back of the tv as is the cable box ( it's very small). The only thing plugged into the surge is the cable box.

Is this safe? Nothing is run through the wall.

[image: surge plugged into extension]

Answer (score 1):

Technically, this is not okay. Wiremold® and other similar products are not typically listed for use with power-supply cords, cordsets, or other similar cables.  They're designed to contain data, communications, and audio video cables. See [this answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/85524/33) for more details.

Check the manufacturer's documentation, to determine exactly what types of cables are allowed in the specific product you're using.

As for plugging the surge strip into the extension cord, that's definitely not allowed. There should be a label on the strip, or in the documentation included with the strip that says not to plug it into another strip of extension cord.

> ## UL White Book 2013
>
> ### Relocatable Power Taps (XBYS)
>
> ...Relocatable power taps are intended to be directly connected to a permanently installed branch circuit receptacle. Relocatable power taps are not intended to be series connected (daisy chained) to other relocatable power taps or to extension cords.

The common solution to this problem, is to use a kit designed for this, like the one described in [this answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/783/33). Though with a system like this, you'll have to cut holes in the wall.

---

If the wire management channel is a listed raceway, then you shouldn't be running power and communications cables through it together. Unless the raceway is divided for the entire length.

> ## National Electrical Code 2014
>
> ### Chapter 8 Communications Systems
>
> #### Article 800 Communications Circuits
>
> **800.133 Installation of Communications Wires, Cables,
>   and Equipment.**
>
> **(A) Separation from Other Conductors.**
>
> **(1) In Raceways, Cable Trays, Boxes, Cables, Enclosures and Cable Routing Assemblies.**
>
> **(d) Electric Light, Power, Class 1, Non–Power-Limited
>   Fire Alarm, and Medium-Power Network-Powered Broadband
>   Communications Circuits in Raceways, Compartments,
>   and Boxes.** Communications conductors shall not be placed in
>   any raceway, compartment, outlet box, junction box, or similar
>   fitting with conductors of electric light, power, Class 1, non–
>   power-limited fire alarm, or medium-power network-powered
>   broadband communications circuits.
>
> ***Exception No. 1:*** Where all of the conductors of electric
>   light, power, Class 1, non–power-limited fire alarm, and
>   medium-power network-powered broadband communications
>   circuits are separated from all of the conductors of communications
>   circuits by a permanent barrier or listed divider.

Comment: The packaging states it's ideal for home/office home entertainment phone/data and power cords. The only warning on manual inside packaging is Not to be used to extend hard wired (permanent) electrical wiring. (Which I don't understand) One power cord maximum. Do not loop cord. My main concern was if it's okay to run an extension from outlet and connect a surge to the female end to power cable box?

Comment: Is there a UL mark on the wire management tube? If so, what UL standards are listed?

Comment: I don't see any UL marks I changed the setup from a extension cord to a monster cable surge protector running straight to outlet thru cable management system along with cable tv wire should be good to go now.

Comment: @user52036 See my update about running power and communications cables in the same raceway.

Comment: The packaging says "Not to be used to extend hard wired (permanent) electrical wiring" because it is a "cable routing assembly" not an electrical raceway. Surface metal raceway (Wiremold) or surface non-metallic raceway can be used to extend permanent wiring. You can buy this with a divider built into it.

Answer (score -1):

Yep, no problem at all. The setup should be under 250 watts (TV plugged into cable box). If the extension cord ever gets warm to the touch, then you'll want to go to a thicker wired extension cord.

Comment: Oops, I read the question right. Or does, "is this safe" somehow mean the world has to be brought up to current Code? I may never know, but only 1-day left to go.